# upgrade javascript library versions in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs

Recently we have made pen-test on Magento 2.3.3 version.

We have received the following issues.

Vulnerable Javascript Library Versions In Use

> adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js
>   adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js
>   adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js

Can we upgrade these library files to latest versions?

How this can be achieved? Can anyone help me with the steps to implement it.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`. create if not exist

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!--Remove default jquery, or it will cause conflict-->
    <remove src="lib\web\jquery\jquery.js"/>
    <remove src="lib\web\knockoutjs\knockoutjs.js"/>
    <remove src="lib\web\jquery\jquery-ui.js"/>
    <!--Include CDN-->
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"></script>
    <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-debug.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"></script>

    <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: hi @Divyesh, what about knockoutjs and jquery-ui file? how can we upgrade them?

Comment: same you can try with knockout .

Comment: can you pls update code for other 2 js as well?

Comment: check updated answer @jafarpinjar

Comment: okay let me try this.

Comment: have u given code for jquery-ui-1.9.2?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100461/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-divyesh).

Comment: pls update in answer with remove tag

Comment: this is not working for me, my magento version is 2.3.3.

Comment: Not working for me. 2.3.3